# The proper place to store urls in React-Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a page user should use for setting content. It consists of two tabs:

1. Create/Edit
2. Extend created item with additional data

   | Basic | Content |

And here is the route

```
  <Route path="campaign" component={Campaign}>
    <Route path="basic">
      <IndexRoute component={CampaignCreate} />
      <Route path=":campaignId" component={CampaignEdit} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="content">
      <Route path=":campaignId" component={CampaignContent} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

As you can see after creating an item I want to update links of both tabs, something like this:

```
/campaign/basic/1234/
/campaign/content/1234/
```

I've put them into Redux store and update them in reducer on `CAMPAIGN_CREATED` action. I'm just not sure if it's proper place to store the links. Probably it would be better to store them in `Campaign` component state?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to store the links. They are stored in the browser's history. Your routes should not know if item 1234 already exists. If we don't know what you want to do with the links, we can't tell you where it is best to store them.

Comment: https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router
This is a wrapper over react-router. This is awesome for applications in react-redux and what it does is give your routed components and in the params it gives the route values as props.

Comment: @JulienD the UI indeed a little more complicated, and I need to keep state of each tab: e.g. if user creates campaign, tab Content should be disabled until Save button is pressed. So on `CAMPAIGN_CREATED` action I undisable the second tab and update its link

Comment: @Anup, thanks will take a look. I was looking on react-router-redux, but it looks like they both have different purpose.